# Project Euler Problem 87, prime power triplets

Tags: python, math

The problem goes:
How many numbers below fifty million can be expressed as the sum of a prime square, prime cube, and prime fourth power?
And here is the link to the problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=87

I'm having a problem when trying to get the right answer for higher inputs. My code in python is below. The function `primestill(n)` returns a generator of all primes below n and works just fine. I would appreciate any help.

```py
def many2(x):
    counter = 0
    s1 = int(x**(1/4))+1
    for i in primestill(s1):
        s2 = int((x-i**4)**(1/3)) + 1
        for j in primestill(s2):
            s3 = int((x - i**4 - j**3)**(1/2))+1
            for k in primestill(s3):
                if i**4 + j**3 + k**2 < x:
                   counter += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: Maybe there are numbers which can be expressed in multiple ways? In that case you would count them multiple times instead of only once.  Maybe a dictionary can help?

Comment: Might there not be some repeats? In other words, one number that can be generated by such sums in more than one way. Try adding the number to a python `set`, and then counting the set size

Comment: @JohanC: great minds ...

Comment: What have you identified as not working? Could you explain how you are trying to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Namely, please explicitly describe your inputs, the expected outputs, and the actual outputs of your algorithm.

This helps us help you and makes your question more useful to others.

Comment: @Zéychin: In fact, he did describe all those things except the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a list of primes up to the largest one that will fit under the 50 million mark.  This would be the largest prime with a square below 50M.

There are only 908 primes up to that largest prime so your loops can just combine these primes.

Note, however, that there are several combinations of primes that can produce the same sum so you will need to ensure that you count each sum only once (using a set for example).

To optimize the process you can break the nested loops once you reach a prime that would go beyond the maximum (50M):

```
# find eligible primes (Eratosthenes sieve)
N        = 50_000_000
maxPrime = int(N**0.5)
sieve    = [0,0]+[1]*maxPrime
p,np     = 1,2
primes   = []
while np<=maxPrime:
    p,np = np,p+2
    if not sieve[p]: continue
    primes.append(p)
    sieve[p*p::p] = [0]*len(sieve[p*p::p])

# nested loops to count distinct sums made from a**2 + b**3 + c**4
sums = set()
for c in primes:
    for b in primes:
        b3c4 = b**3 + c**4
        if b3c4 >= N: break
        for a in primes:
            s = a*a+b3c4
            if s >= N: break
            sums.add(s)

print(len(sums))
```